# How do I define a content 100% while having a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I have this structure for my website as below. How do I define red area as 100%, while it has a sidebar with 260px width and the sidebar is fixed.
[image]

Comment: What you want to achieve finally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use CSS3 you can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
#wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 260px);
}

#sidebar {
    width: 260px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 260px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote when you have the same result as using [calc](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) in a simpler way and more browser compatible?

Comment: Sorry, that's not me.

Comment: @user2915402 1+ This is a good option, especially if support is an issue. It shouldn't have been downvoted.. I just thought i'd mention that you should have a `-moz` prefixed version in there, see the support: http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this will work for you:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dDULw/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="sidebar">
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        wrapper
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
}
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    width: 130px;
    height: 250px;
}
#wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't want a outer.